# из локального репозитория в глобальный

Tags: git, maven, репозиторий

Работаю в IDEA используем Maven, так вот мне для одной задачи установить библиотеку ojdbc7.jar для связи с БД Oracle, это пришлось сделать вручную,так как при добавлении в pom.xml зависимостей не происходило сборки,потому что не мог найти файл в репозиториях.
Так вот, получается создалась эта библиотека в моем локальном репозитории,а когда все запушил(Git) получилось,что у остальных не видит данной библиотеки.
как можно решить данную проблему?не ставить же всем вручную на локальные репозитории

Comment: если у вас есть общий репзиторий можете залить туда. Или может быть лучше подключить её прямо в проект без репозитория и залить в git?

Comment: в общем сделал так-добавил в папку lib файл установщик этой библиотеки.После прописал в pom как плагин maven-install-plugin.туда прописал все параметры-все заработало.теперь у всех при сборке эту библиотеку видит.

Comment: НИКОГДА. НЕ. ЗАЛИВАЙТЕ. БИНАРНИКИ. В. ГИТ. НИКОГДА.

Comment: @zRrr так сработает для ojdbc7, и прочих от Оракла, но не для всех остальных. Но вы правы, сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно для jdbc драйверов и других джаров от Оракла вы можете добавить в ваш (и всех в вашей команде) Maven settings [репозиторий Оракла](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for).

Если вы не хотите (и правильно делаете, что не хотите) добавлять всем и каждому каждый новый репозиторий, которым вы пользуетесь, то вам таки нужен глобальный репозиторий для вашей команды или организации. Поскольку я из [Джейфрога](https://www.jfrog.com), я яростно топлю за [Артифактори](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/). Он опенсорцный, бесплатный, и я тут, чтобы помочь, если что-то не работает.

Именно в конфигурацию Артифактори вы будете потом добавлять репозитории Оракла (а так же все остальные, которые вам понадобятся), и после того, как вы однажды настроили Мавен работать с Артифактори вам не придется менять клиентские настройки для добавления новых репозиториев.

В принципе всё должно быть просто и понятно. После установки (unzip) кнопка "Set Me Up" и [документация](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Welcome+to+Artifactory) - ваши лучшие друзья. Есть ещё [вебинары по вторникам](https://www.jfrog.com/support-service/webinars-upcoming/) (вот [записи](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY0Zjn5rFo4M_yh17EboiWQULzLnSae8U)) и [скринкасты](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY0Zjn5rFo4PR0MqN1MsqXG-t4izCcuUx), и вот конкретно [дока по добавлению репозитория Оракла](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-NetworkSettings).

Comment: Я вас благодарю!и правда решение хорошее!